# Enviar parâmetro ENUM para o C# através do JavaScript

Tags: javascript, web-service, enums

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto na qual tenho que consumir um Web Service em .NET que requer um objeto com alguns parâmetros do tipo Enum.

A chamada é feita pelo Javascript conforme abaixo:

```js
function ConsultarPeriodo(){
   var metodo = 'ConsultarPeriodo';
   var url = baseURL.dadoscliente;
   
   var param = {    
   canal : 'LOJA',   
   empresa : 'Teste',            
   loja : '0',
   usuario : 'Teste'            
   };
   
   return $soap.post(url, metodo, { req: param });  
  }
```

Os atributos "canal" e "empresa" são do tipo enum no Web Service .NET que estou consumindo, dessa forma, preciso enviar os parâmetros de forma que o web service reconheça os atributos enum.

Código da Enum:

```
 public enum EmpresaType
{

    /// <remarks/>
    Loja1,

    /// <remarks/>
    Loja2,

    /// <remarks/>
    Loja3,
}


public enum CanalType
{

    /// <remarks/>
    LOJA,

    /// <remarks/>
    ECOMMERCE,
}
```

Como ficaria o meu código?

Obrigado!

Comment: Só colocar o valor numérico do enum.

Comment: E no caso dos enums não terem sido criados com valores numéricos?

Comment: Escreve o nome do valor.

Comment: Você tem acesso ao código do enum para postar aqui?

Comment: Pronto, disponibilizei!

Comment: Detalhe, a classe que referencia os enums está dentro de uma web reference de um serviço externo que adicionei na minha aplicação, to achando que o problema é este. Fiz um teste criando a mesma classe do Ws externo em minha aplicação, porém criando os atributos como XML atribute, e funfou. Como o WS é externo e não posso mudar, acho que terei que criar uma classe interna para fazer o "de x para".

Comment: Você fez um teste passando os valores numéricos do enum? Ex: function ConsultarPeriodoDAD(){
   var metodo = 'ConsultarPeriodoDAD';
   var url = baseURL.dadoscliente;
   
   var param = {    
   canal :0,   
   empresa : 1,            
   loja : '899',
   usuario : 'Teste'            
   };
   
   return $soap.post(url, metodo, { req: param });  
  }